# lua-CoatPersistent, would this work with Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, luasql

The concept of "lua-CoatPersistent" looks very appealing re higher level usage of a sqlite database in Corona.

Anyone know if this would work under Corona? If you've got it working any tips/learnings re how to get it all setup/working? i.e. any gottcha's that require work arounds?

Link to: "lua-CoatPersistent"

http://fperrad.github.com/lua-CoatPersistent/index.html#documentation

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't install modules. You can use just pure Lua. But I think it should be possible with Corona Enetrprise.